# Cannot read property 'udp' of undefined

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I am trying to make a Chrome App to use UDP, but I can not pass simple UDP creation socket process. This is the error I get in the inspector window:

```
sockets.udp.create: TypeError: Cannot read property 'udp' of undefined
at Object.callback
```

The error is shown at this line:

```
chrome.sockets.udp.create({}, function(....
```

The manifest.json is this:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name"              : "My App",
"description"       : "My App Description",
"version"           : "1.0",

"icons"     : {
                        "16"    : "icons/wl16.png",
                        "48"    : "icons/wl48.png",
                        "128"   : "icons/wl128.png"
}, 

"app" : {
    "background"    : {
        "scripts": ["main.js"]
    }
},

"sockets" : {
    "udp" :  {
            "send"  : ["*"], 
            "bind"  : ["*"]
    }
}
```

The main.js is as follows:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() { 
    console.log('launched')
    sendpack()
})

function sendpack() {
    // Create the Socket
    chrome.sockets.udp.create({}, function(socketInfo) {
        // The socket is created, now we can send some data
        var socketId = socketInfo.socketId;

        chrome.socket.udp.bind(socketId, '127.0.0.1', 1345, function(result){
            console.log('chrome.socket.bind: result = ' + result.toString());
        });

        var arrayBuffer=new ArrayBuffer(2);
        arrayBuffer[0]=65;
        arrayBuffer[1]=66;
        chrome.sockets.udp.send(socketId, arrayBuffer,'127.0.0.1', 1337,function(sendInfo) {
            console.log("sent " + sendInfo.bytesSent);
        });
    });
}
```

I copied everything from Chrome examples, but on the examples it works, on my app it doesnt.

If I print on the console the content of the object 'chrome.sockets.udp' it shows a valid object with 'create' method listed in it:

```
    Object {onReceive: Event, onReceiveError: Event}
         create: function()
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, the bind call had bad object name:

```
chrome.socket.udp.bind
```

it should be in plural, "sockets"

```
chrome.sockets.udp.bind
```

I also mistakenly read the stack trace, from the bottom, not from the top.